# Задача о кузнечике, оптимизация решения

Tags: python

Задача: На числовой прямой сидит кузнечик, который может прыгать вправо на одну или на две единицы. Первоначально кузнечик находится в точке с координатой 0. Определите количество различных маршрутов кузнечика, приводящих его в точку с координатой n.
Мой код:

```
F = [0] * (n + 1)
F[0] = 1
F[1] = 1
for i in range(2, n + 1):
    F[i] = F[i - 2] + F[i — 1]
```

есть ли способы оптимизировать код и сократить затрачиваемое время?

Answer (score -1):

```
    a = 1
    b = 1
    for i in range(2, n + 1):
        a, b = b, a + b
    return b
```